# Solving $T(n)=3T\bigl(\bigl\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\bigr\rfloor\bigr) +2n\log n$ without the Master Theorem

Tags: time-complexity, recursion, master-theorem

I want to solve $$T(n)=3T\bigl(\bigl\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\bigr\rfloor\bigr) +2n\log n,$$
with base case $T(n) = 1$ if $n \leq 1$.

I know that the solution is(with the help of the Master Theorem) $$\Theta(n*log^2(n))$$
I tried without the Master theorem and witht the help of the substuition method I got the following expression
$$T(n)=n+2*n*\sum_{k=0}^{log_{3}(n)-1}log(\frac{n}{3^k})$$

How can I convert this expression into a valid $\Theta(n*log^2(n))$ expression ?

Comment: You have a similar question here:‌ https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/132801/64229

Comment: similar yes, but actually completly different questions.

Comment: Our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) may have some methods for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose $n=3^k$. Then we have:
$$T(n)=3^kT(1)+2n\log \frac{n^k}{3^{k-1}\cdots3^0}=n+2n\log 3^{k^2-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}} =\\
=n+2n\log n \cdot \frac{\log_3 n+1}{2}   $$
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

T(n)=3T(⌊n3⌋)+2nlogn
By substitution method

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!